# Custom image format importer

Tags: operator

I've created an importer for an obscure texture format and I can invoke it as an operator successfully. Because I'm chaining two addons together, (a model importer that also automatically imports textures), I really want to get the resultant image object from the texture import operator so that I can properly . However, because operators can *only* return success or failure codes (eg. `{'FINISHED'}`), I can only really guess as to what the resultant image name might be.

The texture importer `execute` function looks like this:

```
def execute(self, context):
    dtx = DTX(self.filepath)
    image_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(self.filepath))[0]
    image = bpy.data.images.new(image_name, dtx.width, dtx.height, alpha=True)
    image.pixels[:] = dtx.pixels[:]
    # I want to "return" the image to the caller, indirectly, somehow.
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

The model import script calls the texture importer like so:

```
bpy.ops.io_lithtech.import_dtx(filepath=texture)
```

Is there a way to *indirectly* return anything from the execution of an operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you should implement the Operation as a wrapper on existing code. This way you can call an internal method what can return more information. This is also faster as operations creates undo files.

```
def load_dtx_texture(filepath):
        dtx = DTX(filepath)
        image_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filepath))[0]
        image = bpy.data.images.new(image_name, dtx.width, dtx.height, alpha=True)
        image.pixels[:] = dtx.pixels[:]
        return image

class MyTextureImporter(Operator):
    def execute(self, context):
        load_dtx_texture(self.filepath)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class MyMeshImporter(Operator):
    def execute(self, context):

        ....

        image = load_dtx_texture(self.filepath)

        ....

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add [custom properties](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html) to blenders main types. For a global setting add one to scene while adding one to object will let you save a different value per object.

```
bpy.types.Scene.global_prop = bpy.props.StringProperty()
bpy.types.Object.obj_prop = bpy.props.StringProperty()
```

Then you access them like any other property.

```
context.object.obj_prop = image.name
```

For more complex requirements you can create a [collection](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#collection-example) and define a class to hold multiple settings.

```
class SceneSettingItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Test Prop", default="Unknown")
    value = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Test Prop", default=22)

bpy.utils.register_class(SceneSettingItem)

bpy.types.Scene.my_settings = \
    bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=SceneSettingItem)

my_item = bpy.context.scene.my_settings.add()
my_item.name = "Spam"
my_item.value = 1000
```

If you are making an addon, you can add the new properties in `register()` and then delete then in `unregister()`

```
def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.global_prop = bpy.props.StringProperty()

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.global_prop
```

It is also possible to add [custom properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/custom_properties.html) to individual objects. These work like the object is a dictionary, just assign a value to the key, you will also want to check that the property (key) exists before trying to read it.

```
context.object['obj_prop'] = 'something'
```

Comment: And how (related to the question) will help?

Comment: You can't return data from one operator to another, you can store the data in a property and access it from both.